# Using Drools with large (1 million or more) rules

Tags: drools, rule-engine

We are evaluating Drools for a medical-related software application. Our initial rule set will be about 25k, but over time that rule set will grow to well over a million. This is how a typical rule will be structured:

```
when item contains the codes "1234" AND "5678" 
  AND does not include "ABC123" 
then [show some message]
```

The item being evaluated will contain an array of codes as it's facts. What we are trying to do is create a recommendation engine to guide a user to making changes to the item for compliance. My concern is that we cannot selectively filter which rules should fire without Drools evaluating all "when" statements to find the rules that match. If we have millions of rules (some of our competitors have well over 3 million they evaluate) is this something Drools can handle or should we look elsewhere?

The transaction load is not heavy meaning a transaction may only have a few dozen to a few hundred items that need to go through the process. Most of the posts here refer to the opposite problem, evaluating several hundred rules for millions of records.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but still, I would like to answer. Considering the Drools have a RETE implementation it aims to optimize and exclude non-relevant rules. However for this to work your data model must be compatible and use simpler properties in conditions.

I.e. instead of `<array> [NOT] contains <x>` you should do a categorization first and define facts like `<object>.<property>` is set and after that execute rules on it.